# How to create custom sharding logic in envoy?

Tags: envoyproxy

I am setting up a new envoy deployment where the backend is sharded. Is there a way to create custom sharding logic in envoy configuration?

Comment: Late answer:
Not really, though one can look at the redis network filter for ideas. I think most try to use "sticky sessions" aka ["session persistence"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62556973/envoy-sidecar-proxy-session-persistence) which is probably [ring hash](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/upstream/load_balancing/load_balancers) with [use_hostname_for_hashing](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/cluster/v3/cluster.proto#config-cluster-v3-cluster-commonlbconfig-consistenthashinglbconfig). Note, it's possible to use any header.

Comment: Hey Charles, thanks for the answer, actually I solved it using LUA script, but this was 2 years ago. I am not sure about current capabilities