# Envoy sidecar proxy session persistence?

Tags: envoyproxy

I recently came across envoy and it fits very well for my new project. However, I cannot find out if envoy supports something like Sticky Session. Does envoy support session persistence?

Answer (score 1):

Though I haven't used these particular settings yet, I believe what you're looking for is going to be found in the [load balancer sections](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/upstream/load_balancing/overview)). Namely one of the load balancers that do consistent hashing of requests:

- [ring hash](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/upstream/load_balancing/load_balancers#ring-hash)
- [maglev](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/upstream/load_balancing/load_balancers#maglev)

You'll want to choose your load balancer in your [cluster configuration](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/api/v2/cluster.proto#cluster-configuration) (`lb_policy` field) as well as set the specific config for the algorithm (`ring_hash_lb_config` field, etc)

Hope this helps!